# Xamarin forms ListView keep populating data from List<object> instead of simply display the objet once

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I keep encountering this problem no matter what :

The `List<Object> listArticles` is simply keep adding data everytime the page appears ,it keep populating the data over and over again instead of simply display them once

I have tried to declare a tempList everytime the function is called , but no success 
  `List<PlanDefinition> tempListArticles = new List<PlanDefinition>(listArticles)`

How to encouter this problem?

```
async protected override void OnAppearing()
        {

            listArticles= articleView.getArticlesFromPlan();    
            PopulateOrderLists(listArticles);

            base.OnAppearing();
        }

        protected override void OnDisappearing()
        {

            base.OnDisappearing();
        }






  private void PopulateOrderLists(List<PlanDefinition> listArticles)
            {
                List<PlanDefinition> tempListArticles = new List<PlanDefinition>(listArticles);
                OrderTemplate prod = new OrderTemplate();



            for (var i = 0; i < tempListArticles.Count; i++)
            {
                  prod = new OrderTemplate();

                prod.BindingContext = tempListArticles[i].Name;
                 OrderInformation.Children.Add(prod);

             }

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only call your `PopulateOrderLists` once, assumably when the `listArticles` has not been populated, but adjust it to your requirements of when you want to replace the current `listArticles` or add to it...

Example:

```
async protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    if (listArticles != null && listArticles.Count > 0)
    {
       listArticles= articleView.getArticlesFromPlan();    
       PopulateOrderLists(listArticles);
    }
    base.OnAppearing();
}
```

Comment: I literally have no idea how come I haven't thought about this  Thanks!